# Can't get CloudWatch metrics for attached EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance with 1 root and 4 extra EBS volumes attached.I installed CloudWatch agent on my EC2 instance to send disk metrics. I only get Cloudwatch metrics for the root volume.

How do I get metrics for the other 4 attached volumes?

```
My CloudWatch Agent configuration file:

{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "",
                        "log_group_name": ".",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    },
                    {
                        "file_path": "",
                        "log_group_name": ".",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    },
                    {
                        "file_path": "",
                        "log_group_name": ".",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    },
                    {
                        "file_path": "",
                        "log_group_name": ".",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "collectd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60
            },
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                    "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "statsd": {
                "metrics_aggregation_interval": 60,
                "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                "service_address": ":8125"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my volumes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything you're missing - the '*' means get stats for all mount points - assuming the file systems on those volumes are actually mounted on the instance?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html

*resources – Optional. Specifies an array of disk mount points. This field limits CloudWatch to collect metrics from only the listed mount points. You can specify * as the value to collect metrics from all mount points. The default value is to collect metrics from all mount points.*

Comment: It works now. The problem was that I installed the CloudWatch Agent configuration file before configuring the EBS volumes. Stupid mistake :)

Thanks Lupin